# Explanation of complex differential forms in terms of smooth differential forms

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds, complex-manifolds

This question is a reference request (or a detailed answer if anyone is willing to write one).  I want to read a rigorous treatment of complex differential forms for Riemann surfaces (or maybe for more general complex manifolds), but I'm very picky about how I would like these things to be explained.

Let $M$ be a real smooth manifold.  For me, a smooth differential $k$-form is a smooth section of the $k$th exterior cotangent bundle $\bigwedge^k T^{\ast}(M)$ of $M$, a smooth manifold whose underlying set is the disjoint union

$$\bigcup\limits_{m \in M} \bigwedge^k T^{\ast}_m(M)$$
over the points $m \in M$ of the $k$th exterior power of the contangent space of $M$ at $m$.  A chart $(U,\varphi) \subset \mathbb R^n$ defines a canonical basis $dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}, 1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n$ of $\bigwedge^k T_m^{\ast}(M)$ for each $m \in \varphi(U)$, where $dx_1, ... , dx_n$ is the usual basis of $T_p^{\ast}(\mathbb R^n)$ for $p \in \mathbb R^n$.

Now let $M$ be a Riemann surface (or maybe more generally a complex manifold).  Then $M$ is also naturally a real smooth manifold, and we have the space $\Omega^k(M)$ of smooth differential $k$-forms of $M$.

Is there a treatment of complex holomorphic/meromorphic forms on $M$ which explains them in terms of smooth differential forms on $M$?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer to your question is that that's how most texts treat them. You have to complexify the cotangent bundle and think of things in terms of $dz_j$ and $d\bar z_k$ and $C^\infty$ complex-valued functions.